# Increase timeout for requests in Azure API Managment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have a few services which are behind Azure API Managment.
When client send a request it looks like below:

**Client** -> **Azure Api Managment** -> **Service A** -> **Service B**

Sometimes **Service B** responses after 5min, but in the meantime **Client** gets 504 Gateway timeout.
In Azure API Managment I set policy

```
    <backend>
        <forward-request timeout="300" />
    </backend>
```

In documentation I saw below information, but if it is possible to set some settings for network infrastructure in the pipeline?

> The amount of time in seconds to wait for the HTTP response headers to
> be returned by the backend service before a timeout error is raised.
> Minimum value is 0 seconds. Values greater than 240 seconds may not be
> honored as the underlying network infrastructure can drop idle
> connections after this time.

Comment: Usually this policy works. Did you check Client + Service A/B that those can keep up to the 5 minutes timeout?

Answer (score 3):

As the doco indicated, any value greater than 240 won't be reliable. So the best bet for you is to change the implementation a bit if that's in your control.

A simple one could be: instead of waiting for 5 mins, you change the request to "fire and forget", and once Service B has finished its execution, it can write the response somewhere the Service A can access. Your client can then keep pinging to see if the response is available.

This may not be feasible if you don't have control, but just suggested it as a workaround in case you do :)